# how can I solve this error regarding the spacy version

Tags: nlp, spacy

This is the code:
nlp_model=spacy.load('nlp_model')

This is the error:
OSError: [E053] Could not read config.cfg from nlp_model\config.cfg

I am using a pre trained model from spacy v2 and my spacy model is 3.2.1. How can I use this model in my spacy version

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a model from spaCy v2 with spaCy v3. The major version (the first part of the version number) of spaCy and your model need to be the same.

You need to upgrade your model, or, if it's one you trained yourself, retrain it.

Comment: Can you tell how to upgrade a model

Comment: If you follow the install instructions here it will be automatically upgraded. https://spacy.io/models